# 'Self Search / Put your profile to work for you' always empty

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, search, display-template

When I do a 'Self Search' in SharePoint 2013 the counters below 'Put your profile to work for you' are always 0.
I used reflector to determine to logic behind this functionality and looks like the method 'GetClickFrequenciesForUrl' is used to determine these values
So when I run the script below.

```
$url = "http://mysite/Person.aspx?accountname=test%5Caccount"
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$date = ([System.DateTime]::Now)
$ssa.GetClickFrequenciesForUrl($url,$date)
```

We get for example a result of:

```
2 <-- Profile views this month
1 <-- Profile views this week
```

But the 'Self Search' in the People Search still returns zero for both values. (See screenshot below)

[image]

Does this functionality work for anyone else? We have the issue both in a SharePoint 2013 Standard and Enterprise farm.